# Copy line down in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I want to set the copy line down/up keyboard shortcuts to ctrl-alt-down/up. The problem is that i cannot find the proper commands in the keyboard shortcuts.

There are the following:
Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown
Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp

But there is nothing for copying selected lines up/down. Were they removed from 2015 version?

P.S. I know i can do ctrl-c, ctrl-v on a line but this is very uncomfortable for me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign a shortcut to it:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Copy");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
}
```