# How to Create Or Modify Shortcut for Duplicate a Line in VS2015 Keyboard section?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shortcut

I tried to creat or modify a shotcut for duplicate current line in visual studio in keyboar section from option in tool menu , but i cant find any thig that help me to solve this , or at least not in my vs version

I tried some likley answers in stackoverflow and other forums and it didnt work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975493/copy-line-down-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thank you , problem solved by the extension on that post.